# Want to add an image to an existing flash template using XML. I have the .fla file too

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, web, flash-builder

I got an xml and actionscript based Flash web template. It got several pages and images in them. In a page there, I have 7 images loading. I want to add 3 more images to the page. The template is loading other 7 images from an XML file named tfile_main.xml. Which have a code like this for the page I'm talking about :

```
<page name="solutions">
<image imageUrl="_1.png" link="asfunction:_root.more_click_func,0"/>
<image imageUrl="_2.png" link="asfunction:_root.more_click_func,1"/>
<image imageUrl="_3.png" link="asfunction:_root.more_click_func,2"/>
<image imageUrl="_4.png" link="asfunction:_root.more_click_func,3"/>
<image imageUrl="_5.png" link="asfunction:_root.more_click_func,4"/> 
<image imageUrl="_6.png" link="asfunction:_root.more_click_func,5"/> 
<image imageUrl="_7.png" link="asfunction:_root.more_click_func,6"/>
```

```
<pageText><![CDATA[
      Lorem Ipsum
]]></pageText>


<pageText><![CDATA[
      Lorem Ipsum
]]></pageText>

<pageText><![CDATA[
      Lorem Ipsum
]]></pageText>

<pageText><![CDATA[
      Lorem Ipsum
]]></pageText>

  <pageText><![CDATA[
        Lorem Ipsum
]]></pageText>

  <pageText><![CDATA[
       Lorem Ipsum
]]></pageText>

  <pageText><![CDATA[
      Lorem Ipsum
]]></pageText>  

  <pageText><![CDATA[
      Lorem Ipsum
]]></pageText>  



  <pageText><![CDATA[
      Lorem Ipsum
]]></pageText>  



</texts>

    </page>
```

Now all I want to do is load 3 more images in this page. I tried adding this line in the XML file
  
And the CDATA text sections accordingly. But the flash site won't load the image/images. I also have the original FLA file with it. I'm not versed in flash but I got the layer (Sprite 442) where the image structure is visible.

Can anyone guide me what to do? Or at least let me know if it's possible or not? Is there a limit of images that might have been set in the page. I'd be very grateful if someone can guide me in the right direction...

Comment: Did you add 3 more images / lines to the tfile_main.xml above?

Comment: Yes I did Dominic. But they don't show up. I cleared my cache too before testing and the images exist too.

Comment: <image imageUrl="_8.png" link="asfunction:_root.more_click_func,0"/><image imageUrl="_9.png" link="asfunction:_root.more_click_func,0"/><image imageUrl="_10.png" link="asfunction:_root.more_click_func,0"/> If this is not working I think you may need to check the actionScript source code, they may have put a limit on how many images it can hold